# Storing email ID in EmailAddressList facet is not reflected in Experience Profile

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets

I'm trying to store an e-mail address submitted in a form to a new contact (first time) website visitor.

I'm using the below code from [EmailAddressList section - Contact Facets](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/use-core-collection-model-facets.html#idp19008), but the email address is not shown for the visitor in the Experience Profile. However, the Spam key and email address is shown for the visitor.

```
var preferredEmail = new EmailAddress("sample@sitecore.test", true);
var preferredKey = "Work"

var emailFacet = new EmailAddressList(preferredEmail, preferredKey)
{
    Others = new Dictionary<string, EmailAddress>()
    {
        { "Spam",  new EmailAddress("spam@me.com", false) }
    },
};

client.SetFacet<EmailAddressList>(new FacetReference(contact, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey), emailFacet);
```

I tried multiple ways of the above code.. Nothing worked. What is wrong here? I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Please try below piece of code, Its working for me in `Sitecore 9.3`:

```
public void UpdateFacets(string email, Contact contact)
    {
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var changed = SetFacets(email, contact, client);
                if (!changed) return;
                client.Submit();                    
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Could not update the xConnect Email facets", ex, this);
            }
        }
    }
    private bool SetFacets(string email, Contact contact, IXdbContext client)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var emails = contact.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey);
        if (emails == null)
        {
            emails = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(email, false), "Preferred");
        }
        else
        {
            if (emails.PreferredEmail?.SmtpAddress == email)
            {
                return false;
            }
            emails.PreferredEmail = new EmailAddress(email, false);
        }
        client.SetFacet(contact, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, emails);
        return true;
    }
```

One more thing you need to take care, are you defining Email Facet key when you are fetching contact? If not please do that as below:

```
using (var client = _xdbContextFactory.CreateContext())
            {
                Contact contact = client.Get(contactReference, new ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Himmat! Basically, I'm doing this for the first time visitor by creating a contact, so I can't use contact.GetFacet right? I have seen this code but I thought this would not be suitable for my scenario - first time visitor (where Contact.IsNew is true)..

Comment: I am doing the same thing. Getting visitor contact then identify that contact "Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(source, identifier);" and convert that Analytics contact to Xconnect contact. You can use contact.GetFacet.

Comment: Please check the code at https://github.com/AmitKumar-AK/CT.SC/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Controllers/AccountsController.cs to set the email address

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest Email Address facet code that I have

```
var emails = contact?.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey);
if (emails == null)
{
    emails = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(email, false), "Primary Email")
    {
        PreferredEmail = new EmailAddress(email, false)
    };
}
else
{
    if (emails.PreferredEmail?.SmtpAddress == email)
        return false;

     emails.PreferredEmail = new EmailAddress(email, false);
}

client.SetEmails(contact, emails);
```